# Mysql: How to show Realtime display of new inserts and updates to table?

Tags: mysql, logging

Is there a command to show what the most recent inserts and updates to a mysql table are (possibly in a realtime live updating format like the "tail" command)?

Something like syslog but for mysql tables would be excellent. Or if there is a web view of the most recent mysql table updates, that would be even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use general query log and tail it, but it will hurt performance (and it will be painfull).
You can use the mtop utility, which won't show you any meningfull information if the queries are under second but you'll see any slow queries.
And you can output the result of `show processlist` to a file.

All of those will show all queries, so you have to grep the results to receive only inserts/updates. So here is the question: why would you like to see insert/updates?

Comment: Thanks. Inserts and updates are much more important than SELECT's when monitoring for me, because I want to make sure my table is recording information properly.

Comment: I guess there is no easy way to do this, which is somewhat surprising considering how easy it to use to do it for apache.